# Updating timestamp on userLocation change swift

Tags: swift, core-location

I have an application here I get user Location and get timestamp. the problem I am having now is, the timestap continues to update but I want it to only update when the location coordinate changes.

```
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        getLocation(location: locations.last?.coordinate)
}



func getLocation(location manager: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

            let loc = CLLocation(latitude: manager.latitude, longitude: manager.longitude)
            let geoTag = GeoTag()
            let coordinates = Coordinate()
            coordinates.accuracy = Double(loc.horizontalAccuracy).rounded(toPlaces: 3)
            coordinates.altitude = Double(loc.altitude).rounded(toPlaces: 7)
            coordinates.heading = 0.0
            coordinates.lat = Double(loc.coordinate.latitude).rounded(toPlaces: 7)
            coordinates.lng = Double(loc.coordinate.longitude).rounded(toPlaces: 7)
            coordinates.speed = loc.speed

            geoTag.coordinates = coordinates
            geoTag.timestamp = "\(Double(loc.timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970).rounded(toPlaces: 0) * 1000))"

    }
```

more code would be supplied on request

Comment: I have added the code which I tried that did not work and someone still down voted the question. But why?

Comment: Look at significant-change location updates – https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when setting your delegate for locationManager you should add following line too

```
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() //this will call //didUpdateLocations after a significant change in location
```

Or

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = 20  // replace it with what distance in meters you want //this will call you didUpdateLocations method after you travel 20 meters
```